# Display multiple images in a row, but other div no full width

Tags: html, css

I would like to display multiple images in a row, and image made the browser scrollable, but the body or other section width 100% is shorter than my image container.

How to make my text section same width as image section?

[image]

```css
.text {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.images {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="text">
    hi
  </section>
  <section class="images">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Explain more please. you can simply add the same width size to both text and images to have them the same width.

Comment: @MohamadAlAsmar I want to have a multiple images display horizontally(in one row) with min-height: 200px or 100% width in the screen(responsive). the problem is as you can see in the screenshot above, my text area(red color) is shortest than the image. I want the red color area expand automatically based on my image container's width.

Comment: you cannot achieve this with CSS only without moving the red area (".text" section) inside of your images container. In this case, you have to inject some jQuery or Js code.

Comment: What you can do is adding fixed width to the images and give the text container the sum of width for all your images, only if your images count is know & not dynamically changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `width: fit-content;` to body

```css
body {
    width: fit-content;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.text {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}

.images {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="text">
    hi
</section>
<section class="images">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" />
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Nitheesh, the fit-content works, but it cause another issue, which is when browser is super wider, the images will not able to set 100% fit to the screen. refer to this https://jsfiddle.net/x50pva6e/.. if you resize the view to smaller and make it scrollable, it looks great, but if resize to wider, the image container are not 100% in the screen.

Comment: Just add `min-width: 100%;` to body and see whether the issues is fixed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue of images scroll you can add `overflow-x: auto;` & for making text and images same width just use the same width size:

```css
.text {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px; // change to any width size you want
}
.images {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100px; // change to any width size you want
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="text">
    hi
  </section>
  <section class="images">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"/>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: The code you giving is not working. Check is before submit and simply give the `px` size make you have to set the size everytime when add new item

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the 100% of width to `img`, and you should do the same with section, for not making strange things:

```
 .text {
     background-color: red;
     height: 100px;
 }

 section {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
 }

 img {
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: This will not going to work. the parent container of img is section and the width of width:100% will not work. Test it before submit the answer.

Comment: I have tested it on my computer and works perfectly. @James you can try it and find it out

Comment: The css of it clearly is incorrect. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/bfj6d01p/1/ give img 100% make it full width of it parent container which is section, do you think it is correct?

Comment: That link you posted to jsfiddle works exactly same as @Devb wants to do. The images are taking responsive space from its parents and dividing between all images there are.

Comment: I am saying your answer is incorrect. If you think is correct, why not post an working code snnipet

Comment: What you posted alredy works, and it is using what i posted

Comment: Its partent have display flex, so they are getting responsive and take that space between all images

Comment: @Maidagan do you mind to share a jsfiddle? I tried to use what u suggested, but not working. the text area still not full width, can see the blank area behind... https://jsfiddle.net/o13h09sq/

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do, you gant to take out the white border it has in all the sides? Then you should add `body {  margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }` to your css. This a good practices when you use css. If this is not what you need, can you specify better your question??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk5uy3am/1/